# How to permit arrays with hash in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following params in Rails 4:

```
{"delivery_time":"10","delivery_type_id":"1","order_items":[{"count":"5","item_id":"1"}],"order_status_id":"1","user_id":"1","action":"create","controller":"api/v1/orders"}
```

There is the following strong params:

```
params.permit(:user_id, :order_status_id, :delivery_type_id, :delivery_time, order_items:[])
```

But this code returns hash without 'order_items' array. I think the reason is hash in array. Please, tell me, how can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd assume it's same as with associations ie `params.permit(:user_id, :order_status_id, :delivery_type_id, :delivery_time, order_items:[:count, :item_id])`?

Comment: You are right. Make an answer and I'll mark it as right one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can include nesting arrays, for your example it would be:

```
params.permit(:user_id, :order_status_id, :delivery_type_id, :delivery_time, order_items: [:count, :item_id])
```

Others can find out more here - http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 7):

As described [here](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), you can permit the nested attributes as below.

```
params.permit(:user_id, :order_status_id, :delivery_type_id, :delivery_time, order_items_attributes:[:count, :item_id])
```

However, remember to add following line to accept nested attribute in model. For example:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items
end
```