# Strong parameters in rails with array as root object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of objects being passed to my controller with this structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fruit_ids": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "fruit_ids": [4, 5, 6]
    },
]
```

The root object, is not a `{}`, and instead is a array. I'm not sure how to write a strong params state for this case. I have tried

```
params.permit [:id, fruit_ids: []]
```

and other similar options, but it wasn't permitting it.

Edit:

I'm not sending a JSON object in my request body. I'm sending a JSON array. When I inspect the value of `params` in my controller, this is the result:

```
{
    "_json" => [
        {"id"=>1, "fruit_ids"=>[1, 2, 3]},
        {"id"=>2, "fruit_ids"=>[4, 5, 6]}
    ],
    "format"=>"json",
    "controller"=>"...",
    "action"=>"..."
}
```

Comment: Check about wrap_parameters. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774972/rails-wrap-parameters-vs-include-root-in-json-what-is-the-difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permit arrays with hash in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796880/how-to-permit-arrays-with-hash-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should always send a JSON objects as a param, when you don't explicitly give a key for object, it takes `_json` as is the case with your params.

Anyway to write a strong parameter in your case, you can do something like,

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
    "_json" => [
        {"id"=>1, "fruit_ids"=>[1, 2, 3]},
        {"id"=>2, "fruit_ids"=>[4, 5, 6]}
    ],
    "format"=>"json",
    "controller"=>"...",
    "action"=>"..."
}

params.permit('_json': [:id, fruit_ids: []]) # You need this line.

# => {"_json"=>[{"id"=>1, "fruit_ids"=>[1, 2, 3]}, {"id"=>2, "fruit_ids"=>[4, 5, 6]}]}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct answer:

```rb
params.require(:_json).map { |params| params.permit(:id, :fruit_ids) }
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. thanks Pere Joan Martorell.