# Permitted parameter still Unpermitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

With the parameters below

> Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"",
>   "work_week_form"=>{"work_hours"=>[{"day"=>"monday", "start_hour"=>"8",
>   "end_hour"=>"17"}, {"day"=>"tuesday", "start_hour"=>"8",
>   "end_hour"=>"17"}, {"day"=>"wednesday", "start_hour"=>"8",
>   "end_hour"=>"17"}, {"day"=>"thursday", "start_hour"=>"8",
>   "end_hour"=>"17"}, {"day"=>"friday", "start_hour"=>"8",
>   "end_hour"=>"17"}, {"day"=>"saturday", "start_hour"=>"8",
>   "end_hour"=>"17"}, {"day"=>"sunday", "start_hour"=>"8",
>   "end_hour"=>"17"}]}, "button"=>""}

Why `params.require(:work_week_form).permit(work_hours: [])` raise `Unpermitted parameter: :work_hours`?

Comment: can you try by change `params.require(:work_week_from).permit(:work_hours)`

Comment: Same outcome. Also `.permit('work_hours' => [])` doesn't work.

Comment: Try explicitly permitting the nested attributes too `params.require(:work_week_form).permit(work_hours: [:day, :start_hour, :end_hour])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of array of hashes you need to define keys individually, Like we need to specify in case of parent child relationship. [check here](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

You can check solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796880/how-to-permit-arrays-with-hash-in-rails-4/20798461) as well.

```
params.require(:work_week_form).permit(work_hours: [:day, :start_hour, :end_hour])
```